# Determine type of child object

Tags: c#, inheritance

So, I have a base object called LogEvent and I create other classes derived from that such as an ExecuteEvent or a SubmitEvent. When I try to get the type of the specific instances they always come back as LogEvent. Here's each of the classes' definitions:

```
class LogEvent
    {
        public List<LogEventAttribute> eventAttributes = new List<LogEventAttribute>();
        public int clusterId;
        public DateTime eventTime;

        public LogEvent(List<LogEventAttribute> eventAttributes)
        {
            this.eventAttributes = eventAttributes;
            this.clusterId = Convert.ToInt32(eventAttributes.Find(p => p.name.Equals("Cluster")).value);
            this.eventTime = DateTime.Parse(eventAttributes.Find(p => p.name.Equals("EventTime")).value);

        }
    }

    class SubmitEvent : LogEvent
    {
        public string submitHost;

        public SubmitEvent(List<LogEventAttribute> eventAttributes)
            : base(eventAttributes)
        {
            this.submitHost = eventAttributes.Find(p => p.name.Equals("SubmitHost")).value;
        }
    }

    class ExecuteEvent : LogEvent
    {
        public string executeHost;

        public ExecuteEvent(List<LogEventAttribute> eventAttributes)
            : base(eventAttributes)
        {
            this.executeHost = eventAttributes.Find(p => p.name.Equals("ExecuteHost")).value;
        }
    }

    class TerminatedEvent : LogEvent
    {
        public bool successful;

        public TerminatedEvent(List<LogEventAttribute> eventAttributes)
            : base(eventAttributes)
        {
            this.successful = Convert.ToBoolean(eventAttributes.Find(p => p.name.Equals("TerminatedNormally")).value);
        }
    }

    class LogEventAttribute
    {
        public string name, type, value;
        public LogEventAttribute(string name, string type, string value)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.type = type;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
```

And here's where I try to do different things based on the type of class:

```
switch (currentEvent.GetType().ToString())
                    {
                        case "ExecuteEvent":
                            ExecuteEvent currentExEvent = currentEvent as ExecuteEvent;
                            item.SubItems.Add("Job executed by " + currentExEvent.executeHost);
                            break;
                        case "SubmitEvent":
                            SubmitEvent currentSubEvent = currentEvent as SubmitEvent;
                            item.SubItems.Add("Job submitted by " + currentSubEvent.submitHost);
                            break;
                    }
```

The switch always gets passed over because currentEvent.GetType().ToString() always comes out to LogEvent.

Edit: The problem was that I was first creating these different classes differently. Here's the faulty code:

```
LogEventAttribute eventTypeAttribute = currentEventAttributes.Find(p => p.name.Equals("MyType"));
                string eventType = eventTypeAttribute.type;
switch (eventType)
                {
                    case "SubmitEvent":
                        logEvents.Add(new SubmitEvent(currentEventAttributes));
                        break;
                    case "ExecuteEvent":
                        logEvents.Add(new ExecuteEvent(currentEventAttributes));
                        break;
                    case "TerminatedEvent":
                        logEvents.Add(new TerminatedEvent(currentEventAttributes));
                        break;
                    default:
                        logEvents.Add(new LogEvent(currentEventAttributes));
                        break;
                }
```

On the second line where I'm getting the property "type" from the eventTypeAttribute, I should instead be getting the value property. I was using the type property to determine the type of the value the attribute has stored in its value property. Argh, TGIF.

Comment: Try using `currentEvent.GetType().Name` instead.

Comment: Because it IS a LogEvent

Comment: @Chris, that also comes out to LogEvent

Comment: Are you sure your creating the derived types? Can you put breakpoints in their ctors? Or mark `LogEvent` as abstract so you can be sure you're not creating objects of that type?

Comment: @Jared, so what's the best way to determine what the kind of LogEvent is?

Comment: @stereoa Yeah, my mistake. I assumed (wrongly) that `Type.ToString()` outputs the full class name (including namespace or assembly qualified name). I second BinaryWorrier's take: debug and make sure you're passing the concrete types you think you are. EDIT: Wait, `ToString` is different than `Name`, I think I'm right on this; you need to double check your instances.

Comment: @stereoa If you're okay with `if/elseif/elseif` you can use `if (currentEvent is ExecuteEvent)` and so on.

Comment: If I sublcass ExecuteEvent, I'll hit your default in your switch.  That's bad.  Don't switch on class name.  C# gives you the `is` operator - use that instead.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier Argh, you found the bug. I was constructing all these objects as LogEvents because when I was determining which type of event it was it was falling through to the default switch state because I was checking the wrong variable.

Comment: @stereoa Consider making `LogEvent` abstract, unless you really need to make instances of that base class.

Comment: @Chris I think I do want instances, I basically make log events from a parsed text file, then Add all those LogEvents to a Job class that has a List<LogEvent>. Please tell me if I would want something different I'm only self taught :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually get type object for `LogEvent` from `GetType`, then you have instances of the `LogType` class, not of any of the derived classes. However, I don't think that you get what you think that you get.

Using `ToString()` on the `Type` object will return the complete namespace, e.g. `"MyApp.ExecuteEvent"` rather than `"ExecuteEvent"`.

Use the `Name` property instead:

```
switch (currentEvent.GetType().Name)
```

Comment: That was a secondary step that helped as well as me discovering a bug in my code (See my edit in the OP).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `is` keyword for type checking, like `currentEvent is ExecuteEvent`, which also removes the potential for typos. Additionally, `currentEvent is LogEvent` will return true because, like Jared said, it IS a `LogEvent`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ExecuteEvent executeEvent = currentEvent as ExecuteEvent;
if (executeEvent != null) 
{
 item.SubItems.Add("Job executed by " + currentExEvent.executeHost);
}
```